# Windows Games Explorer Play/Support Tasks

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, installation

I'm trying to get a game I'm working on to integrate with the Windows Games Explorer.  So far I have embedded a Game Definition Format XML file as a resource in my binary (my actual executable) and I've been able to register the game inside the Games Explorer.

However, In Vista, the play tasks and support tasks that I have defined in my GDF don't display.  The only valid link that shows up in Vista's context menu is a link to the 'Saved Games' folder for my game.  In Windows 7, it all works *fine*.

What do I need to do to get play tasks and support tasks to display correctly in Windows Vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, you have to create the actual shortcut ( `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\GameExplorer\{yourguid}\PlayTasks\0\Play.lnk` ) And you probably want to get the GameExplorer path with a known folder id

Comment: So presumably this means that I would have different behaviors for every target OS.  Start menu/Desktop for XP, custom shortcut for WGE in Vista, and auto created play/support tasks in Win7. Irritating, but doable. I will try this.

Comment: This led me down the path I needed.  Ultimately, I have my installer calling out to a heavily modified version of Microsoft's GameuxInstallHelper.dll from the (March 2009) DirextX SDK samples. The code in that sample as written seems to fail needlessly on extra COM init calls. In any event, it seems to be working now.

Comment: Note the latest version of [GameUxInstallHelper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/GameuxInstallHelper-6a9335ca) is on MSDN Code Gallery...